# Problems with Inner Join - Querys and DataTables - Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm having an issue while working with several data tables, I ran the query and it's *"working fine"*. But, the data is not being inputted on the other data extension that I need to be.

The **objective** is that I've 5 data extentions with information that I need to connect, to have a better use of that data. I want to create one data extentions where connect the information from those 5 tables where the lines are correctly given the information. The code:

```
SELECT Cliente.id, Cliente.nome, Cliente.email, Cliente.cpf, Cliente.bairro, Cliente.cidade, Cliente.uf, Cliente.telefone1, Pedido.valor_itens, Pedido.valor_cobrado, Pedido.data, Item_Pedido.produto_id, Item_Pedido.descricao, Produto_Area.area_id, Area.nome as area_nome
FROM Cliente
INNER JOIN Pedido ON Cliente.id = Pedido.id
INNER JOIN Item_Pedido ON Pedido.id = Item_Pedido.pedido_id
INNER JOIN Produto_Area ON Item_Pedido.pedido_id = Produto_Area.produto_id
INNER JOIN Area ON Produto_Area.produto_id = Area.id
```

Comment: You should check the field types on your Data Extension, and the cardinality between the the tables. I have seen this happen when  trying to inner join on a many to on table, without deduping the data

Comment: @Data_Kid I checked and it's everything fine. The character counts, data types and the order between the tables etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I did solve it. Marketing Cloud allows the query to run, but when there isn't a result (because it didn't meet all the requirements), it doesn't populate the DE. Although it appears "green" on the GUI, because it did run the query, but didn't found any record do input.